# hintText not appearing inline

Tags: flutter, textfield

I'm trying to align a icon and text within a textfield however the output is not as I planned, below is my code:

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    leading: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
      iconSize: 30.0,
      onPressed: () {
      },
    ),
    title: Text('Food Delivery'),
    centerTitle: true,
    actions: <Widget>[
      FlatButton(
        child: Text('Cart (${currentUser.cart.length})', 
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15.0),),
        onPressed: () {
        },
      )
    ],
  ),
  body: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
              borderSide: BorderSide(width: 0.8)
              ),
              hintText: 'Search Food or Restaurants',
              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, size: 30.0,),
              suffix: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                onPressed: () {

                },
              )
          ),

        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
 }
}
```

I can't see to find the issue, the output on the simulator and an actual device is the same:

[image]

I thought maybe it's an issue with the search icon, however, decreasing the size of the icon didn't change the output.  Can anyone suggest a fix to make the hint text appear inline with the icon.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is
       contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 
    15)
 Try reducing it. The vertical padding adds padding from top and bottom both.

Answer (score 0):

As you already told, the problem is with the icons in suffix/prefix !
So this is an alternative !

```
Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 0.8)),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(
                  Icons.search,
                  size: 30.0,
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 10),
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border:InputBorder.none,
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                      hintText: 'Search Food or Restaurants',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                  onPressed: () {},
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

[image: Screenshot]